# Проблема с структурами c#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Journal[] journals = new Journal[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
journals[i] = GenerateJournal();
Console.WriteLine(journals[i].ToString());
}


 Console.Read();
 }

 public struct Journal
 {
 public string Name;
 public string Family;
 public string Bykva;
 public int Nomer;
 }
 static Journal GenerateJournal()
 {
 string[] name = { "Павел", "Егор", "Михаил", "Александр", "Максим", "Мария", "Александра", "Анна", 
 "Виктория", "Алиса" };
  string[] fam = { "Смирнов", "Иванов", "Кузнецов", "Попов", "Соколов", "Лебедев", "Козлов", 
  "Новикова", "Пугачева", "Балябкина" };
int[] nom = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
string[] bykva = { "а", "б", "в", "г" };

Journal newJournal;

Random rand = new Random();

newJournal.Name = name[rand.Next(name.Length - 1)];
newJournal.Family = fam[rand.Next(fam.Length - 1)];
newJournal.Nomer = nom[rand.Next(nom.Length - 1)];
newJournal.Bykva = bykva[rand.Next(bykva.Length - 1)];

return newJournal;

}

}

}
```

Не выводит ничего. Запускается консоль и сразу выключается программа.
Суть программы в том, что дан список из 10 учеников и нужно вывести тех у кого имя и фамилия совпадают.
Подскажите пожалуйста. в чем тут ошибка?

Comment: приведенный код, даже компилироваться не должен. Попробуй заменить `= GenerateJournal()` на `= Journal.GenerateJournal()`

Comment: Не сработало, пишет что не содержит определения в текущем контексте.

Comment: Попробуйте GenerateJournal сделать public и замените Read на ReadKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно изменить функцию вывода на еран :

```
          {
              journals[i] = GenerateJournal();
              Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}\t ",journals[i].Name);
          }
```

Ну и в том же духе добавить вывод фамилии, и всех нужных Вам даных.
Ведь вы просто обращаетесь к обьекту, а нужно к некоторой переменной в этом случае.